# Javascript for-loop only goes as far as the first array element

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to compare user input to elements of an array and change the value of a variable accordingly but the for-loop is not iterating through all elements of the array, it stops at the first. Why isn't it comparing the input to all elements of the array?

```
<p>Month</p>
// Get Number Of Month (Jan = 1, Feb = 2, Mar = 3, etc.)
<input id="monthNumber" type="number"><br><br> 

<button onclick="calculator()">Show</button><br><br>

<span id="result"></span><br><br>
```

And the code

```
function getNumOfDays(){
    var array = new Array(1,3,5,7,8,10,12, 01, 03, 05, 07, 08);
    var monthNumber = document.getElementById("monthNumber").value;
    var x;

    for(var i = 0; i <= array.length; i++) {
        if(monthNumber == array[i]) { 
            x = 31; 
        } else {
            x = 30; 
        } 
        return (array[i] + " " + x)  //it always returns 1 to array[i]
    }
} 

function calculator2() {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=getNumOfDays();
}
```

TRY THIS ON A BROWSER, PLEASE:

```
    <p>Month</p>
        // Get Number Of Month (Jan = 1, Feb = 2, Mar = 3, etc.)
        <input id="monthNumber" type="number"><br><br> 

        <button onclick="calculator()">Show</button><br><br>

        <span id="result"></span><br><br>

        <script>
    function getNumOfDays(){

        var array = new Array(1,3,5,7,8,10,12, 01, 03, 05, 07, 08);
        var monthNumber = document.getElementById("monthNumber").innerHTML;
        var x;
    console.log(monthNumber);
        for(var i = 0; i <= array.length; i++) {
            if(monthNumber == array[i]) { 
                x = 31; 
                break;
            } else {
                x = 30; 
            }   
        }

        return x;
    } 


    function calculator() {

      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=getNumOfDays();
    }



    </script>
```

Comment: "_Why isn't it comparing the input to all elements of the array_" Because after you compare the first one you then RETURN from the function.

Comment: That makes no sense, if you need the result then return, but if you need it to continue iterating then dont return.

Comment: It seems like what you really want to do is to call the function inside a loop, not have a loop inside the function... _For every month in the array call the method to figure out how many days_...

Comment: Also, side note: your logic is flawed here. You're assuming every month that doesn't have 31 days will have 30 days. What about February?

Comment: the user inputs a value. this value gets compared to those inside the array. if i matches, var x gets a value (31). If it doesnt, var x = 30. When button is clicked, x is displayed. it's very simple.

Comment: Yes, it is so simple we aren't sure how to explain it any differently than we already have - move your return statement outside of the loop.

Comment: I did! It always returns 30.

Comment: First of all, why would you even need to return `i`? That's just the index of the iteration. Second, you have to move the `return` statement outside the for loop. Saying it's `simple` but not understanding this is a contradiction. Just return x after the for loop is completed (outside the scope).

Comment: I'm returning [i] to see why it always returns 30. I don't need [i], just x.

Comment: Johnny, you're asking for help saying it stopped after 1 iteration. We told you why. If it's always returning 30, that's a separate issue.

Comment: Does it print 30 if you enter `08` for the month? Maybe you should just learn to use the debugger a bit to see what your code is doing and when.

Comment: @csm_dev hi. it always returns 30, except with 1. That's because the loop only loops to the first element of the array, which is 1.

Comment: @csm_dev I can tell you're trying very hard to be nice, lol. I'm having same issue here. Just doesn't seem to get it.

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet hi, sorry if i'm not being clear. all i need is that, when the user input a value, if that value is inside the array, it gets displayed the number 30 or 31. that's all. I'm sorry if i seem a little distressed. I'm always getting this kind of feedback here. I know you two are trying to help. I just don't know why the loop is not comparing the input to all elements of the array.

Comment: because you're ending the iteration by `return`

Comment: but if i put the return out of the loop, it still returns only the value 30, for inputs diiferent than 1, which means it doesnt iterates through all the array, only until the first, EVEN THOUGH return is out of the loop. What am I not getting? please?

Comment: It _does_ iterate through the whole array (which you would see if you ever actually used your debugger like I said) - it always returns 30 because you have a logical error.

Comment: Can you debug what `monthNumber` is? Because if it's `undefined` then it will always return 30. Make sure you're comparing against an actual value. This is why csm told you to debug, because we have no idea what you're comparing, we can only look at your code.

Comment: ok. i made the wrong question. what i should have asked is how do i make it work. instead, i posted that it wasnt working because of a specific error, made this error clear by making the code return it, and messed up the post. i'm sorry.

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet i'm comparing to a value coming from user input. user type it, then the for-loop executes, with the if statement.

Comment: @JohnnyJohnny See my answer, I made a working example for you. I tried to highlight what you did wrong, and what to do to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first and foremost issue was that you were returning before iteration was complete.

Another issue is (possibly) you should just look for `innerHTML` of element with id `monthNumber`. (if monthNumber is undefined then it will always return 30, impossible to know without more code/debug data you find since it seems you didnt debug at all).

Another issue is that you weren't breaking the loop if the `monthNumber == array[i]` was met. Think of it this way, let's say `monthNumber` is `3`, and sure enough the `monthNumber == array[i] (i = 3)` is true. But you're still iterating, so now when it goes to next iteration `array[i] = 5` you're overriding `x` to now equal `30` and not `31`. So once you find that the condition was met, you must break out of loop.

I wrote a working example that does what you want (minus February). Some advice though, try not to be rude to people answering your question. It was fairly unclear what you wanted, and your actual question was answered many times. I know it can be tough, but try to stay relevant to what you're asking, and if you're stuck on something else then ask another question.

[See here](https://jsfiddle.net/anpvxp62/)

```
<p id="monthNumber">
2
</p>

console.log(getNumOfDays());

function getNumOfDays(){
    var array = new Array(1,3,5,7,8,10,12, 01, 03, 05, 07, 08);
    var monthNumber = document.getElementById("monthNumber").innerHTML;
    var x;

    for(var i = 0; i <= array.length; i++) {
        if(monthNumber == array[i]) { 
            x = 31; 
            break;
        } else {
            x = 30; 
        }   //it always returns 1 to array[i]
    }

    return x;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your patience. i'm very new to javascript, and it's very frustrating sometimes. One thing i don't get: the code you posted is returning 2, instead of 31 or 30, and there's no place for user input. Should i run it on a browser?

Comment: No, the code I posted returns 30 or 31 (return as in, the function returning value). I just put 2 in the html element as a way to test for my self. The 2 is irrelevant, you can put anything you want. I get the value from html element (so `2` in this case), and use that to compare to all the elements in the array. If it's in the array, it will return 31 and `break` the loop, otherwise it will return 30. Again, February doesn't have 30 or 31 days so you'd need to revise that logic a bit. This should get you started, and answers all your questions you had.

Comment: I was just using your own logic, you seem to have had a element in which you were checking the value from. The element I made is completely irrelevant. I only made it bc i have no idea what kind of element you are using. You didnt post that code. Nor should it matter, this is more than enough to get you started.

Comment: thank you. i tried your code on the browser, and it stil doesn't work: when i click the button, it always gives me 30. what i think is happening is somehow i'm not being able to explain what i need. But thank you for your help. i'll see if i can formulate the question better. thank you. i mean it.

Comment: What are you talking about? Did you go to my fiddle? It works fine.

Comment: i used on the browser, i'll put the code exactly on an edit, please, copy to an html editor and see for yourself. just a minute.

Comment: You do understand that if it works in fiddle and not in your local text editor, then clearly you didn't just copy and paste.

Comment: I do. But please, jus try it on a browser. Maybe you'll understand what i'm not being able to explain. I edited the original post. Please, try it on a browser just as I wrote, ok?

Comment: I did try it on a browser, I posted the fiddle link. Are you making sure your element has a value to it? Did you console.log `monthNumber` ?? If you have my code (but not html) and you still get 30, that means `monthNumber` is undefined.

Comment: yes. if you just copy what i posted, past it to an html editor, then run on a browser, i promise you'll see i'm not lying.

Comment: i dont think youre lying i just dont think you're trying hard enough to figure it out. Can you at the very least just `console.log(monthNumber)` before the for loop and see what number it is?

Comment: i did what u said, updated the original post to show what i did, and still, all i get is 30. did you run what i posted on a browser? if you input, say, 3 on input field, does it show 31 when u click the button? ? if u input 1, does it show 31 when you click? because all i'm getting is 30.

Comment: you didnt do what i said, i said to `console.log(monthNumber)` before the for loop.

Comment: ok. did what u said, updated the original post for you to check it if i did it right, and now i'm getting this message: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: literally all im looking for is: "yes I did console log, heres the value". You keep saying you did what I said..

Comment: i think you didn't copy what i posted to an html editor, then run it on a browser, because i have the browser open, with the code posted, and that's the result. Just do it. U will see that, even with all that u said, it is still wrong. u don't have to assume i'm not doing what u said. try it for yourself the way i'm trying, copy YOUR code that i posted on the original post, run it on a browser, and you'll see. forget fiddle, it lacks some bits of code there. I dont know how to edit there. try it the way i said.

Comment: i'm asking for a leap of faith, here. please. try it on a browser, with the code above.

Comment: you were right. i just had to change the `var monthNumber = document.getElementById("monthNumber").innerHTML; ` to  `var monthNumber = document.getElementById("monthNumber").value; ` what was missing from the previous code was the break you added. thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Your `return` statement is inside the `for` loop. Put it outside.

```
function getNumOfDays(){

// Months with 31 days
var array = new Array(1,3,5,7,8,10,12, 01, 03, 05, 07, 08);

var monthNumber= parseInt(document.getElementById("monthNumber").value);
if(monthNumber==2)
   return (monthNumber + " " + x)
//variable x will change to 30 or 31 according to month user chose
    var x=30;

for(var i = 0; i <array.length; i++)// You had a problem here too. `i`should not be equal to array.length

  if(monthNumber== array[i]){
      x = 31; 
      break; //This is not necessary, but it improves performance
 }
return (monthNumber + " " + x)  //it always returns 1 to array[i]

}
```

Comment: No, it's not that, because, the result is always 30 on the code. The loop is not working properly.

Comment: See my solution now. Why do you have 01,03,05??

Comment: and why do you want to return array[i]?? Shouldnt it  return just x?
Anyways, does it work now?

Answer (score 1):

It's because of this:

```
return (array[i] + " " + x)  //it always returns 1 to array[i]
```

The return automatically ends the loop after the if or the else is done. You should print that result, not return it.